# Why do classic google maps and the modern google maps show different types of driving times?

Tags: google-maps, distance, routing, time

As I am currently working on a project, where driving times are quit important, I've noticed that classic google maps and modern google maps show different types of car driving times.

While the modern google maps shows driving times with and without traffic, the classic gui shows only driving times with traffic and one figure, which is not further specified. BUT: driving time with traffic is always lower than the not further specified figure. How can this be? How can low traffic be faster than calculating the driving speed without traffic?

Has anybody any ideas? Am I getting something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution could be: Modern maps show 30 or 50 km/h for situations with/without traffic. The classic map show 40 km/h as a way of representing both situations as a single number.